# Проблема события click Jquery на IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

Добрый день!

Есть код

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frload1').prop('action', '/Ajax/load_lenta_image') ;
    $('#photo_form').click();
});
```

Суть - подстановка action в форму для ajax загрузки изображений (через iframe). 
На десктопной версии и на Android код работает отлично, на IOS отказывается.

НО если перед `$('#frload1').prop('action', '/Ajax/load_lenta_image') ;` добавить `alert(1);`, то код срабатывает после закрытия уведомления.

Кто сталкивался, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: race condition? "на IOS отказывается" - в чем это выражается? Маленький человечек вылезает из компьютера и говорит "Отказываюсь!"?

Comment: Не срабатывает событие .click без алерта.

Comment: Та-а-ак. Что делает (должен делать) `'#photo_form'` на click?

Comment: #photo_form - это button, который делает submit формы (форма имеет target - iframe, т.е. происходит загрузка изображения через ajax)

Comment: У нас с Вами тоже - race condition. Или Вы добавите полное описание проблемы в Ваш вопрос, или мне надоест Вас к этому подталкивать.

Answer (score 1):

Так как в вопросе упомянут *iframe*, ставлю сто против одного, что дело в очередности загрузки страницы в *iframe* и выполнения `$(document).ready` родительской страницы. В связи с отсутствием достаточной информации, могу предложить использовать обработчик события `onload` элемента `iframe`.

Kaк по-русски "race condition"?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko - Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Внезапно, (для меня это было неожиданно) нужно добавить для `#photo_form` css свойство: `cursor: pointer` и click() начинает работать на IOS.

Comment: пробовал, безрезультатно